# how to give select field for every row in datatable and in select box need to see data of row

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a table with data getting from database and am using datatable for that data now i need a select box for every row like i have three rows in a table

`firstname||number||email`

`sairam||123||gau@gmail.com`
 `gau||1234||gauuiu@gmail.com`

now when i click on first name there is should be a select box and i need to get sairam and gau in that select box soo when i select sairam need to get entire coloumn.and am using below code for jquery datatables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myTable').dataTable({
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [

          'excelHtml5',

          'pdfHtml5'
      ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Your is not clear and moreover you should tried then ask question

Comment: @Gautham Goud Please update your  question  properly.

Comment: You want like this :https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/07Lrpqm7/2355/  .What i understood from your quetion

Comment: my question in i want to use individual column search by select input in datatable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your question, i assume that on editing first cell for any row in your datatable, you want a select box to appear and select box should have certain values.

here is the code that should help you

```
 $('#myTable').dataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [

                    'excelHtml5',

                    'pdfHtml5'
                ]
            }).makeEditable({
                sUpdateURL: "",//url to handle the update call when lets say a name is selected for name select box
                sUpdateHttpMethod: "POST",
                "aoColumns": [
                        {
                            //settings for name column
                            indicator: 'Saving selected name',
                            tooltip: 'Click to select name',
                            loadtext: 'loading...',
                            type: 'select',
                            onblur: 'cancel',
                            submit: 'Ok',
                            loadurl: '',//url to load select box items
                            loadtype: 'POST',
                            width: '25%',
                            cssclass: "required"
                        },
                        {
                        //settings for number column
                        },
                        {
                        //settings for email column
                        }
                        ]

            });
        });
```

the code above uses the jquery jeditable plugin for inplace editing
https://plugins.jquery.com/jeditable/

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @ yash kumar datatable edit inline functionality plugin is paid not an open source.

Comment: my question in i want to use individual column search by select input in datatable

Comment: @DipakThoke the variant of this plugin is issued under mit license here:-https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wikis/Overview.wiki

Comment: @GauthamGoud can you post a mockup of what you want. you wrote-"i want to use individual column search by select input in datatable", but where will select box will appear(please add mockup/snapshot of what you have in mind) individual column search has been achieved here https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ehhfsrfq/2/